# css clip alternative to display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, cross-browser

The idea is that a table cell has "n" number of divs inside. I have been using the display css property to show one cell content ore other on moseover(hover) but render process can be improved if I use "clip rect()" css property to show one content or another within the cell.

I have managed to make this work in the following example, but as u can see, as I show one portion or other of the clip rect, the shown area moves regarding the top property.

Changing top is expensive render wise. can I go around it somehow?

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/nn1d9xe7/1/

html:

```
<table>
  <tr class="tableRows">
    <td class="tableCells">
     <div class="clipper">
      <div class="vals">
        <p>Cell val. 1</p>
        <p>Cell val. 2</p>
        <p>Cell val. 3</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="editBtn">
        <p>Edit</p>
      </div>  
     </div>  
    </td>

    <td class="tableCells">
     <div class="clipper">
      <div class="vals">
        <p>Cell val. 1</p>
        <p>Cell val. 2</p>
        <p>Cell val. 3</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="editBtn">
        <p>Edit</p>
      </div>  
     </div>  
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="tableRows">
    <td class="tableCells">
     <div class="clipper">
      <div class="vals">
        <p>Cell val. 1</p>
        <p>Cell val. 2</p>
        <p>Cell val. 3</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="editBtn">
        <p>Edit</p>
      </div>  
     </div>  
    </td>

    <td class="tableCells">
     <div>
      <div class="vals">
        <p>Cell val. 1</p>
        <p>Cell val. 2</p>
        <p>Cell val. 3</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="editBtn">
        <p>Edit</p>
      </div>  
     </div>  
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

css:

```
    table{
    outline:2px solid black;
}
.tableCells{
    position:relative;
    background:lightBlue;
    outline:2px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;

}

.vals{
background:lightGreen;
}

.editBtn{
background: yellow;
}


.clipper{
outline:1px solid red;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
top:0px;
width:100%;


clip:rect(0px,100px,15px,0px );



}

.clipper:hover{
outline:1px solid red;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
top:-56px;
width:100%;


clip:rect(56px,100px,70px,0px );



}


p{
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I am curious to why you want to optimize this so much? To me this seems like an inexpensive operation and not something you want to worry about in modern webdev?

Comment: @KristianBarrett I don't want to add/remove DOM nodes(as editing some css properties does) on a big table cause the repaint takes time(average cell n° = 3000). I wan't any form of interaction to render at 60fps(phones/tablets also) and avoid Jank. Check csstriggers.com to c cost of css properties change from default or update

Comment: U can compare the difference(between display, opacity, clip...) regarding performance on the timeline(chrome 4example)